# How can the "exclusion" reaction of a machine/software be expressed?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to express that some models of a machine (controlled by a computer) don't **take** specific parameters **into consideration**. The verbs "take into consideration", "take notice", "take into account" don't seem to express a machine's reaction.

What would you suggest? Should I use these verbs or should I reformulate my statement to totally avoid them.

Comment: You could say the machine *ignores* or *disregards* specific parameters.

Comment: What's wrong with "take into account." For example, when the computer is low on battery power, it enters standby mode automatically. *The currently running programs **are not taken into account**.* / *The computer enters standby mode, **regardless** of what programs are currently running.*

Comment: "Does not compute, Will Robinson!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the difficulty may be related to the use of passive nature of the statement.  Perhaps instead something like:

> The machine ignores these specific parameters.
>   It bypasses this rule set.
>   It dispenses with any of these problematic situations.

Answer (score 2):

*Specific parameters **do not register** with this machine.*

E.g.

> [Hansen Solubility Parameters in Practice](https://books.google.ca/books?id=efMbTvlfc8wC&pg=PA87&dq=%22to%20register%20with%20the%22%20sensor&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jTs1VYf-NNTbsASL24D4BA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22to%20register%20with%20the%22%20sensor&f=false) - Page 87 Steven Abbott and
> Charles M. Hansen
>
> The simplest case would be that each sensation had a unique sensor
> which had a unique HSP for optimal binding. ... to be happy in the
> sensor area, but **there must be other molecule-specific attributes for the aroma to register with the sensor**.
>
> -
>
> [The Handbook of Brain Theory and Neural Networks](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Av6qWhtw0-EC&pg=PA66&dq=%22to%20register%20with%20the%22%20sensor&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jTs1VYf-NNTbsASL24D4BA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22to%20register%20with%20the%22%20sensor&f=false) - Page 66 Michael A.
> Arbib - 2003
>
> **Auditory and somatosensory cues** are transformed to **register** with the visual map in the colliculus for the control of saccades.

Answer (score 2):

Some parameters are not in [scope](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scope?&o=100074&s=t) for|of the model

> **noun**
>   1. extent or range of view, outlook, application, operation, effectiveness, etc.
>
> e.g.: an investigation of wide scope.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Answer (score 0):

Why not *use*?

Models A, B, and C use parameter X to...
Models D, E, and F do not use parameter X.